# Run index() into only specific html tag

Tags: jquery, indexing

I want *index()* runs into only specific html tag *.row*

But, right now *index()* runs all the DOM, and give me all the *.twocol* in the document.

I have the full example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/brunogarcia/SRUkt/
Why?

```
$("a.mostrar").live("click", function(event) {
alert($(this).parent(".row .twocol").index(".row .twocol"));

        <div class="row">
            <h3>Row 1</h3>
            <div class="twocol"><a href="" class="mostrar">text</a></div>
            <div class="twocol"><a href="" class="mostrar">text</a></div>      

        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <h3>Row 2</h3>
            <div class="twocol"><a href="" class="mostrar">text</a></div>
            <div class="twocol"><a href="" class="mostrar">text</a></div>      

        </div>
```

Comment: Ok, now works within _:visible_ http://jsfiddle.net/brunogarcia/KXYqw/

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
$(this).parent().index();
```

It will give you the 1-based index of the link's parent among its siblings.

[See your updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/SRUkt/4/)

If this is not what you want, you have to explain better.

Comment: It's not really the 1-based index; it's the 0-based index of the tag amongst the tags in that parent tag. In this example, there just so happens to consistently be one non-link tag at the beginning of the list of siblings, but a simple change to the DOM invalidates that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index, you can use

```
$(this).parent(".row .twocol").index(".row .twocol:eq(2)")
```

it will get the 3rd one.